# '"Windows Backend object has no attribute 'iso-path' - see log for details.' error when trying to install

Tags: wubi, installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 in windows XP, Everything went as before until the countdown clock reached zero, then I got "Windows Backend object has no attribute 'iso-path' - see log for details. It's done it three times now. (Formatting in between)

The end of the log says

```
======
11-01 17:20 DEBUG TaskList: New task check_iso
11-01 17:20 DEBUG TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
11-01 17:20 DEBUG CommonBackend: Checking Y:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
11-01 17:20 DEBUG Distro: checking Ubuntu ISO Y:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
11-01 17:20 DEBUG Distro: wrong size: 8094031872 > 900000000
11-01 17:20 DEBUG TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
11-01 17:20 ERROR TaskList: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 579, in get_iso
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 565, in use_iso
AttributeError: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
11-01 17:20 DEBUG TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
11-01 17:20 DEBUG TaskList: # Finished tasklist
11-01 17:20 ERROR root: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 120, in select_task
File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 579, in get_iso
File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 565, in use_iso
AttributeError: 'WindowsBackend' object has no attribute 'iso_path'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't install Wubi from a USB. It copies the entire USB partition as the ISO image and then checks the size in a strange check that is supposed to distinguish between a CD ISO and a DVD ISO. The check considers a valid CD ISO is between 550MB and 850MB (roughly).

So in this case you have an 8GB ISO. And that's why it failed.

Instead of using the USB, place the CD ISO in the same directory as wubi.exe on your local drive, make sure you remove the USB from the computer, and then run wubi.exe from the local drive.

Answer (score 1):

For me, just disconnecting from the Internet solved my problem. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Disconnecting from the Internet did not help me so I had to consider my moves one by one. 
I admit I am a newbie with ubuntu and this is my first time trying to install it, incorporated in one of my local disks under Windows.

So, I tried the installation from a pendrive [aka. USB stick] and got the same error. The thing was that my .iso file and the Wubi.exe were not in the same direction. 
Solution: Start Wubi from the pendrive - it will ask you to deinstall the failed one first. Do so but do not try installing yet. Simply copy Wubi.exe in the same direction where the .iso file is. Then, remove the USB stick and start Wubi.exe from the directory itself. The installation will go smoothly! :P

P.S. Talking about Ubuntu v. 11.10

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I solved it by opening the iso file in powerIso and installing from there.