# 'WindowsBackend' object has no atribute 'iso_path' error when installing from CD

Tags: system-installation

I start installing ubuntu 11.10 from CD to have dual boot with windows 7 and 10 seconds before end i get message : An error occured :

```
'WindowsBackend' object has no atribute 'iso_path'
```

For more information, please see the log file....

I use HP laptop probook 4710s.

Comment: Is it an install inside Windows? I mean WUBI? If so: http://askubuntu.com/q/84198/32037

Answer (score 1):

I found a Question on Launchpad, that seems fitting to your problem.
You may have a look: https://answers.launchpad.net/wubi/+question/175550